# How to instantiate a fragment in a PagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I have the following custom pager adapter, which I'm calling from my activity and passing some parameters. Everything is working fine. I get the strings that are in latitude and longitude.

```
class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;

    private final ArrayList<String> latitude;
    private final ArrayList<String> longitude;


    public CustomPagerAdapter(Activity context,ArrayList<String> latitude,ArrayList<String> longitude) {
        this.context = context;
        this.latitude= latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return latitude.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == (object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listpager_imageView);
        TextView latitude = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listpager_text);
        TextView longitude = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listpager_title);
        latitude.setText(this.latitude.get(position));
        longitude.setText(this.longitude.get(position));


        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
    }
}
```

I also have this map fragment, which is working fine if I'm calling it from an activity like this:

```
 FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
// Replace the contents of the container with the new fragment
    ft.replace(R.id.your_placeholder, New MapFragment());
// Complete the changes added above
    ft.commit();
```

this is the fragment:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    MapView mapView;
    GoogleMap map;
    private double latitude,longitude;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewtopager, container, false);


        // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
        mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
        map = mapView.getMap();
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());

        // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(1.56, 43.433), 10);
        map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mapView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

}
```

What I would like to do is to introduce the fragment in the CustomPagerAdapter, so when I'll call the CustomPagerAdapter from an activity everytime I swipe, a new fragment will be loaded. `your_placeholder` id is this

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Is it possible to do this ? I'm sorry if I haven't explained the problem properly. I'll try to edit it if you have any questions. Thank you.

Edit: Another question that I have-> When I press the back button the pagerActivity just starts again, it doesn't close it. I have to press twice to close it.

Comment: Have you checked _FragmentPagerAdapter_ already?

Comment: No, I have not. I thought I could just put a fragment within my pagerAdapter without having to modify everything.

Comment: can you school me again on what you want you want to swipe and have a map fragment load or?

Comment: I just asked if it's possible. I'll have a look at the FragmentPagerAdapter then..

Comment: @Elltz do you see anything wrong with my pager ? If I press the back button once it starts the activity again. I have to press it twice to exit. Is this normal ?

Answer (score 0):

It sure is possible to replace fragments with PagerAdapter; I use it. Since someone brought it up, FragmentPagerAdapter class may make processing fragments easier, hence the namesake. I have not used it though. Either way the code should be similar.

About pressing the back button. If you want to have that effect. Here is sample code from yours:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
// Replace the contents of the container with the new fragment
ft.replace(R.id.your_placeholder, New MapFragment());

ft.addToBackStack(null);       // support the Back key

// Complete the changes added above
ft.commit();
```

Note: Add method **addToBackStack**